# Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end Express, отправка картинки с сервера клиенту

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему, хочу на запрос GET отобразить html-страницу с картинкой, при отправке html файла и картинки выкидывает ошибку Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end[image: клиент] [image: сервер]. Если отправить что-то одно, то работает корректно: только html [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения], только картинка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения], сам код для этого запроса:

```
app.get('/cityBikes', (req, res, next) => {
    let files = ['/cityBikes.html', '/img/Десна Вояж Gent.jpg'];
    res.sendFile(__dirname + files[0]);
    fs.readFile(__dirname + files[1], (err, data) => {
        res.end(data);
    });
});
```

, извините, если предоставил мало информации, первый раз пишу в stackoverflow

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/errors.html#errors_err_stream_write_after_end    - была сделана попытка взывать  stream.write() после вызова  stream.end()

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Надо видеть код, обрабатывающий этот запрос на сервере

Comment: Он под картинками

Comment: Вы не должны отдавать картинку вместе с html. Вы отдаёте html, браузер его парсит и отправляет новый запрос за картинкой и в ответ на него вы отдаёте картинку.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно ответить на запрос c картинкой? Надо писать новую конструкцию app.get('запрос на картинку', (req, res) {
})?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, отлавливая все запросы:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    if (req.url === картинка) {
        fs.readFile('путь до картинки', (err, data) => {
            res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
            res.send(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Всем спасибо за помощь.